# Problema con git push: fatal: No configured push destination

Tags: git

Tengo un problema con `git` y es que al intentar hacer `git push` a mi repositorio remoto, me sale el siguiente error:

```
$ git push
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name
    
    git push <name>
```

Adjunto captura de la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta. Intenté copiar y pegar el código en mi editor de texto pero por alguna razón pegó una foto. Como no se puede reproducir, supongo que es un error tipográfico.

Comment: Ayudaría mas si copias y pagas los comando tal cual los escribiste junto con la foto, esto va a dar mayor legibilidad

Answer (score 4):

Primero agrega el repositorio remoto, para ello se utiliza el comando `git remote add origin <url>` colocando la `url` de tu repositorio. Ejemplo:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
```

Finalmente para hacer `push` al repositorio remoto ejecutas el comando:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Nota que `origin` es el alias que le diste al repositorio remoto cuando lo agregaste con `git remote add` y `master` es el nombre de tu rama actual. Lo que quiere decir esta sentencia en castellano es:

> Sube (`push`) al repositorio remoto (`origin`) los cambios en mi rama `master`.

Los argumentos `-u origin master` solo tienes que especificarlos la primera vez, luego simplemente usas `git push`.

En los mismos mensajes de la consola te dan detalles de lo que te acabo de comentar. Puedes consultar más detalles en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.github.com/es/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) en español de github.

Comment: Una forma sencilla de especificar la rama actual, sin usar su nombre, es con `@`: `git push -u origin @`. Le hice upvote a la respuesta, en todo caso. +1